# Add timespan to date in separate cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, date

I am using Excel to do a spreadsheet for training. I have columns named `Date completed` and `date to review`.

Is there a way that if I enter, e.g. 7/8/15, into date completed, that the date review column will automatically change; for example, a year after, e.g. 7/8/16, without me having to input and work it out every time I update it?

There are lengths from 1 year to 3 years and I want the date to review to automatically input when I change the date completed so I know the next time to review.

Answer (score 2):

To add a year in your review field, you use the formula

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

where `A1` is a reference to your first date field.